# What package format do I need for my AWS Server (debian or Linux)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, elasticsearch, debian

I want to download Elasticsearch on an AWS Server. The AWS Server has the following configuration:

```
Plattform: Ubuntu (Inferred)
Plattformdetails: Linux/UNIX
```

The following packages exist:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/install-elasticsearch.html

It says:

```
The tar.gz archives are available for installation on any Linux distribution and MacOS.

The deb package is suitable for Debian, Ubuntu, and other Debian-based systems. Debian packages may be downloaded from the Elasticsearch website or from our Debian repository.
```

So should I download the `tar.gz` or the `deb package`?

Answer (score 1):

The `tar.gz` you will have to unzip into a location you pick, and probably do some setup yourself. It's just a bunch of files zipped up without any sort of "installer". The `deb` package will use Ubuntu's package manager to install it onto your system. I would recommend always trying to use the package manager when possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so there is no problem downloading the linux file, assuming I am able to set it up correctly?